# Django Field Rename

Tags: django, field, rename

Is that possible to rename field ?

Example:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    nameP = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ageP  = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nameP
```

And now I want to print in my addPerson.html :

Name : Person 1
Age  : 18

Thank you !

Comment: You could use `verbose_name`

Comment: Something like `nameP = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `verbose_name` within the field parameter like this:

```
nameP = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
ageP  = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Age')
...
```

You can also do this on `Model` classes as well with the `Meta` class. Say your `Person` class was actually named `PPPerson`, like this:

```
class PPPerson(models.Model):
    nameP = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
    ageP  = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Age')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Person'
        verbose_name_plural = 'People'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `verbose_name' parameter:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    nameP = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
    ageP  = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Age')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nameP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename field in model:

1. Edit the field name in the model (but remember the old field name: you need it for step 3!)
2. Create an empty migration

`$ python manage.py makemigrations --empty myApp`

3. Edit the empty migration (it's in the migrations folder in your app folder, and will be the most recent migration) by adding to the operations list

`migrations.RenameField('MyModel', 'old_field_name', 'new_field_name')`

4. Apply the migration

`$ python manage.py migrate myApp`